# JNA native code sometimes fails with error code 127: "The specified procedure could not be found"

Tags: java, winapi, dll, jna, kernel-module

I'm using [`JNA`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) to call native code. This works most of the time but sometimes I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 127: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Usually this exception happens the first time this is called if at all. If the call succeeded, all following calls will succeed as well as long as the `Java` program runs.

My code looks like the following for instance:

```
boolean succeeded = MY_KERNEL_32.DebugSetProcessKillOnExit(false);
if (!succeeded)
{
    checkForKernelError();
}
```

`checkForKernelError()` is defined as follows:

```
private static void checkForKernelError()
{
    int lastErrorCode = MY_KERNEL_32.GetLastError();

    if (lastErrorCode != 0)
    {
        String lastErrorMessage = formatMessage(lastErrorCode);
        String errorMessage = lastErrorCode + ": " + lastErrorMessage;
        throw new IllegalStateException(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

The idea is to call a `Windows API` native code in combination with some other process running on `Windows` and always assert that it succeeded afterwards. But why do I sometimes get `The specified procedure could not be found` when the native function never changes and should always be found. What could be the problem here and how can it be fixed so it consistently works like it should?

Comment: Just to confirm, does the error really occur with Windows libraries (like Kernel32 as you mentioned)? Under what circumstances does the error occur? How often? Can you give a complete minimal reproducable snippet? How are you loading the libraries?

Comment: Additionally, use `Native.getLastError()`. JNA stores the error code. If you call `GetLastError()` that you've mapped yourself, there may be other underlying system calls in the middle that give you the wrong status code.

Comment: Also, you might already be aware, but JNA does provide *some* mappings out of the box in the [`jna-platform`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.5.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/package-summary.html) artifact.

Comment: Are you running on an Oracle VM or something like the Excelsior JET?

Comment: @cubrr: I'm running on an Oracle VM and I will try the `Native.getLastError()` which sounds like it could work. :)
Since it happens randomly, making a reproducible example is hard.